# How to scale up batchnode in cocos2d correctly?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, scale, retina-display, sprite-sheet

I want to support HD display for my new app with only one set of images. I wrote a container for the sprite so that it can scale the image up based on it's anchor point when needed. But when I create the images in spritesheet, I cannot find a way to achieve the same thing. Since all the images are loaded in a batchnode, and I can't find a way to scale up the batchnode correctly, say scale each image in the batchnode based on a different anchor point. So I'm wondering if anyone know any solutions to this problem?

Thank you in advance for any reply!

Answer (score 2):

Simply disable Retina display support if you do not use HD images. Doing so will have your game look exactly the same on Retina devices as on SD devices.

You will only see improved image quality on Retina devices if you provide separate HD images. If you don't, there's no point in enabling Retina mode.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but based on my test, I do see gained quality in Retina display because I'm using one set of high quality image I guess.